# How to run swank of slime with clisp without dump?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, clisp, slime, swank

## Summary

swank always dumps when using clisp as an infferior-lisp on cygwin Emacs.

## Details

- emacs on cygwin
  GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-cygwin) of 2019-08-30
- slime
  20200219.2239
  I use no customize after installing slime from melpa.
- clisp

```
$ clisp --version
GNU CLISP 2.49+ (2010-07-17) (built on moufang [10.128.134.88])
Software: GNU C 5.3.0
gcc -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -W -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit -O -DENABLE_UNICODE -DDYNAMIC_MODULES -Wl,--stack,0x800000  libgnu.a /usr/lib/libintl.dll.a /usr/lib/libreadline.dll.a -lncurses  /usr/lib/libiconv.dll.a -L/usr/lib -lsigsegv
SAFETY=0 TYPECODES WIDE_HARD SPVW_PAGES SPVW_MIXED
libsigsegv 2.10
libiconv 1.14
libreadline 6.3
Features:
(REGEXP WILDCARD SYSCALLS I18N LOOP COMPILER CLOS MOP CLISP ANSI-CL COMMON-LISP
 LISP=CL INTERPRETER LOGICAL-PATHNAMES SOCKETS GENERIC-STREAMS SCREEN GETTEXT
 UNICODE BASE-CHAR=CHARACTER WORD-SIZE=64 PC386 UNIX CYGWIN)
C Modules: (clisp i18n syscalls regexp)
Installation directory: /usr/lib/clisp-2.49+/
User language: ENGLISH
Machine: X86_64 (X86_64) DESKTOP-V41DUSU [192.168.33.1]
```

- swank messages

```
Process inferior-lisp floating point exception (core dumped)
```

- clisp dump

```
$ cat lisp.exe.stackdump
Exception: STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO at rip=0010051C01B
rax=0000000000000001 rbx=0000FFFFFFFFFFFF rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=FF7FFFFFFFFFFFFF rdi=00006FFFFFF31A10
r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =0080000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000100589108 r12=0000000100589004 r13=0080000000000000
r14=0004000100547110 r15=0004000100547110
rbp=0080000000000000 rsp=00000000FFFC8CD8
program=C:\cygwin64\lib\clisp-2.49+\base\lisp.exe, pid 72, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```